# Create http request after model is saved

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've made an ip + port checker in python but I want to make it into a website with django, everything is kinda working but I have some issues, I don't know how to make it so it doesn't create an infinite loop, and if 1000 ip + ports are added to the database I don't want it to make 1000 connections at once.

I haven't tried much because I don't know what to try.
I've tried using `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor` with max_workors set to 10 so it only does 10 connections at a time but that kinda works but still have the issue of making an invite loop.

the model save function

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # overwrite save function
    super().save(*args, **kwargs) # saves to database
    checker.check(self) # calls check function
```

the check function inside checker.py

```py
def check(modelthing):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        modelthing.is_alive = True # sets is_alive to true if everything went ok
    except:
        modelthing.is_alive = False # sets is_alive false when exception is thrown
    modelthing.save() # ISSUE it saves the model again and it calls the save function that calls checker.check(self) witch creates an infinity loop
```

It saves it to the database, calls the check function. (first block of code)
Then it checks if the ip + port is alive. (second block of code) and the last line saves it again witch calls the first block of code and that block calls the checker function again and this repeats over and over.

I don't know if it is the best way of doing it but i managed to make it working with ThreadPoolExecutor and that solves the second issue but it still creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *dependency injection*, pass an additional keyword argument (e.g. `call_check`) in `save` that decides whether `checker.check(self)` needs to be called again:

```
def save(self, *args, call_check=True, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if call_check:
        checker.check(self)
```

And in `checker.check` pass the argument value as `False`:

```
def check(modelthing):
    ...
    ...
    modelthing.save(call_check=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to remove `checker.check(self)` from your `save` function and call it separately after you saved your object.

So in your application code you could do something like this:

1. modelthing.save()
2. modelthing.check()